# How can I export Pgzero (pygame zero) to .exe?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pgzero

I am just wondering how can I make an executable from *pgzero* game.
I have tried for hours with no success.
*pyinstaller* always had some errors during exporting, or opening .exe .
Or exe file did nothing after opening (and I also have tried waiting for so long)
I have tried bypass script which exported me .egg file instead of .exe

script https://gist.github.com/AnthonyBriggs/cac72989c2dd3c4aeb7475237079d2fb

Can you guys help me ? thanks.

Comment: You need to add the code to the question. A link to an off-site resource is not sufficient. Links to external resources tend to break and the resource may no longer be available in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have refactored the whole game into `pygame` and used `auto-py-to-exe` tool which makes only one *exe* file from whole game (with images, sounds and icon included)